# Huge KDE System Tray icons in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: kubuntu, icons, kde, plasma

My KDE system tray icons are huge in Kubuntu 14.04:

[image: Huge KDE System Tray icons]

Notice that the Skype and wicd icons are sized properly, these are not KDE apps. However the KDE apps' icons (Klipper and Volume Control) are huge. I have checked and I already have the  ["Improve systemtray on HiDPI displays" patch](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=kde-workspace.git&a=commitdiff&h=c4b22caae66c2af26276c4c842fde82e883f0af4) applied on my system:

```
file:a/plasma/generic/applets/systemtray/package/contents/ui/IconsList.qml -> file:b/plasma/generic/applets/systemtray/package/contents/ui/IconsList.qml

--- a/plasma/generic/applets/systemtray/package/contents/ui/IconsList.qml
+++ b/plasma/generic/applets/systemtray/package/contents/ui/IconsList.qml
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@
     id: root_item

     property int icons_size:     24  ///< Size of icons, icons are square i.e. width == height
-    property int icons_margins:  4  ///< Margins for icons
+    property int icons_margins:  icons_size/3  ///< Margins for icons
     property alias icons_number: repeater.count  ///< [readonly] Number of icons
     property alias model:    repeater.model; ///< Model for grid
     property int cell_size: icons_size + 2*icons_margins ///< [readonly] size of grid cell

file:a/plasma/generic/applets/systemtray/package/contents/ui/main.qml -> file:b/plasma/generic/applets/systemtray/package/contents/ui/main.qml

--- a/plasma/generic/applets/systemtray/package/contents/ui/main.qml
+++ b/plasma/generic/applets/systemtray/package/contents/ui/main.qml
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@
     property int minimumWidth:  JS.MINIMUM_SIZE
     property int minimumHeight: JS.MINIMUM_SIZE

-    property int iconSize: Math.min(root_item.width, Math.min(root_item.height, JS.ICONS_SIZE))
+    property int iconSize: Math.min(root_item.width, Math.min(root_item.height, theme.defaultFont.mSize.height < 20 ? 24 : theme.largeIconSize)) //Math.min(root_item.width, Math.min(root_item.height, JS.ICONS_SIZE))

     // Data Models
     property list<ListModel> models: [
@@ -112,7 +112,7 @@

             content: IconsList {
                 id: popup_area
-                icons_size: JS.ICONS_SIZE
+                icons_size: root_item.iconSize
                 model: model_popup
             }
         }
```

Considering that I already have the patch, **what might be the cause of the huge KDE System Tray icons**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have  "Improve systemtray on HiDPI displays" AND you have not set proper DPI. You should set True DPI value for you monitor in "Appearance-Fonts" setting in the System Control. If this does not work, set proper DPI in Xorg settings.

Comment: Thank you! After removing the checkbox "Force Fonts DPI" in "System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Fonts" the icons appear normally.

Comment: Wow, tried so many things to fix this issue, including pulling out much of my hair, before finally realizing all I had to do was force a dpi setting to fix it.